# What am I? (solve this riddle)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> In turn of a century,
> sensory is its admission.
>
> With a turn of it's face,
> A place with no embrace.
>
> I might entail of it nature,
> Would it just taper?
>
> If in its place Is a brace,
> of so much Grace.
>
> Patter and turn it might,
> It shall write history.
>
> If it's just and true,
> How great shall be the view.

**What am I?**

Comment: Is the capitalised "Is" on line  7 a part of the riddle?

Comment: Also "Grace" on line 8

Comment: Could I trouble you for a hint?

Comment: @Brandon_J what stands the same through history? (even if it changes, it remains untouched) what is the object of mystery yet it continue on? Man might might make it, but never truly understand it.

Comment: @hat yes :) good catch, it's to bring into focus something integral.

Comment: @hat Same with Grace, (what rhymes with Grace? Pace... )

Comment: Hmm..that first sentence leaves me absolutely clueless.

Comment: @Brandon_J https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_of_the_century

Comment: Along the lines of @hat, are "it's" in place of "its" in verse 2 and lowercase "of" in verse 4 hints? And the fact that the setup is in 3rd person while the main question is in first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you:

> Hands of a clock

In turn of a century,
sensory is its admission.

> Tells time

With a turn of it's face,
A place with no embrace.

> Hands turn on a clocks face

I might entail of it nature,
Would it just taper?

> They sometimes have a tapered shape

If in its place Is a brace,
of so much Grace.

> not sure

Patter and turn it might,
It shall write history.

> Ticking sound

If it's just and true,
How great shall be the view.

> They should show the time correctly

Comment: Yes! I love it! Thanks for your answer. (brace, allows such a thing to be held in place, yet the "" is graceful)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A Year

In turn of a century,
sensory is its admission.

> Years signify decades and centuries.

With a turn of it's face,
A place with no embrace.
I might entail of it nature,
Would it just taper?

> Years end.

If in its place Is a brace,
of so much Grace.
Patter and turn it might,
It shall write history.

> Each year, history is made.

If it's just and true,
How great shall be the view.

> if it is a new year, people celebrate, possibly with fireworks.

Comment: Sooooo Close, "" is not the only bystander (see answer above) "" cant write history...(though some might argue this) Ty for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Might it be a 'typewriter'

In turn of a century,
sensory is its admission.

> This one I'm not sure I think typewriters over the century have evolved to computers which can perceive and aid people more.

With a turn of it's face,
A place with no embrace.

> When someone is writing a story on a typewriter and someone else starts working on the story aka a change or turn of face it is not accepted as it is not the original writers story anymore

I might entail of it nature,
Would it just taper?

> when using a typewriter for long the ink will start to taper

If in its place Is a brace,
of so much Grace.

> I think working on a typewriter has it owns grace as everything works so well together, the paper moving from right to left as every letter is typed.

Patter and turn it might,
It shall write history.

> When writing on a typewriter every letter will make a tapping sound, the paper will turn and you can write history of your own.

If it's just and true,
How great shall be the view.

> When someone writes a good story it will be admired and read by many others.

Comment: wow, this is sooo good, but not what i meant. TY for this i will treasure it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Luck

In turn of a century, sensory is its admission.

> Gambling was used as a form of celebration on Dec 31 1999

With a turn of it's face, a place with no embrace

> Someone can encounter bad luck just as easily as good luck

I might entail of it nature, would it just taper?

> Relying on luck as a survival strategy tends to end in disaster more often than not

If in its place Is a brace, of so much Grace.

> Religion can serve as a way of comprehending the whims of luck and fortune, such as with karma or sin

Patter and turn it might, it shall write history.

> Many of the most interesting stories in history had no clear or definitive outcome, thus being "up to luck"

If it's just and true, how great shall be the view.

> Great and miraculous things can be accomplished with just a bit of luck

Comment: i love how you used the words to your definitions, not what i was going for, though a great answer indeed :) TY for this.